# IOS swift navigation controller correct architecture

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, uinavigationcontroller

I've just started developing my first iOS app and am trying to maintain some good architecture ideas so I learn the right way.

My app has two distinct parts that are not related between each other.

I already implemented the first part, it uses a navigation controller to go between a main view controller that needs to be active all the time and a second view controller that is shown to select options momentarilly.

I now want to implement the second part of the app and I'm wondering what is the best way to transition back and forth between my initial view controller, managed by the navigation controller and the new part of my app.

I don't really want to simply push the new view controller on top of the root navigation controller view since it seems to indicate a link between both that I don't really want.

Is it possible to create a second navigation controller for the second part of my app and change between the two navigation controller?

Sorry if it's too vague of a question, just trying to learn the best practices without really knowing what is possible in the first place.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a fit for `UITabBarController`... you can have multiple tabs, and you can put a distinct Navigation Controller in each one.

Comment: So a Tab bar controller as the root, two branches to distinct navigation controllers?  That sounds like a pretty good fit. Would switching between both navigation controllers create new instances every time? From my very small experience with Tab Bar controller, the different tabs seem to coexist which I wouldn't need.

Comment: No, switching tabs only creates that tab's child-controller once. You don't need to think of them as "coexisting," other than the fact that they will *persist*. So, if you push 3 controllers onto the Nav in Tab-A, then switch to Tab-B and navigate through its controllers, then switch back to Tab-A... you'll be returned to where you left-off in Tab-A - you won't be "starting over."

Comment: Thanks a lot for the precision, really helps me understand all of it. Last little thing, you say they persist but don't coexist. Does that mean I don't have to worry about my non-focused tab slowing down the focused one?

Comment: hmmm... well, in theory, you shouldn't be doing anything in one view controller that would interfere with another. If you were, you'd probably want to re-think your design - like push process-intensive tasks onto background threads. You can also stop things (like animations, I suppose) when you receive the viewWillDisappear message, if you really need to. In general, though, this is a pretty typical use-case scenario.